# How do I pass the output of SelectKBest to the cross_val_score function?

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I have the following code here:

I am trying to retrieve the 20 best features from my dataset and then test the cross validated score with the Random Forest Classifier however once I've performed SelectKBest I recieve an output: X_train_selected and X_test_selected and it's not immediately obvious to me how I pass this to the cross val score function.

Answer (score -1):

You don't need to separate train and test data for cross_val_score. The function itself just takes care of it. When passing the features set, you need to pass the complete feature set, not `X_train` and `X-test`

First seperate the target variable

```
target = df['result']
```

Then run the selectKbest and get the column names like you did, but this time instead of splitting the X into train and test, just pass them as single data set like this

```
X = clean_df[colnames_selected]
```

Then pass the `X` and `target` to cross_val_score

```
scores = cross_val_score(forest, X, target, cv=10)
print("Reduced features: mean of the scores: {:.2f}".format(scores.mean()))
```

The whole point of the function is to perform cross validation on the dataset and return the scores using the estimators provided.

You can also use pipelines to make this whole process more easier in go [like this example](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/auto_examples/feature_selection/plot_feature_selection_pipeline.html#sphx-glr-auto-examples-feature-selection-plot-feature-selection-pipeline-py).

Comment: So when I fit the selection function like so: selected_features = selection.fit(X_train, y_train) should I pass clean_df and target instead of X_train and y_train?

Comment: Yes that will do as well. Just be sure to pass `clean_df['colnams_selected']` instead of just `clean_df`. If this answer helped you, can you please mark it as the correct one :)

Comment: @WewLad But that may (will) give you wrong results because you are using already trained selected features results on the whole data

Comment: @VivekKumar he is asking for the fit function, the features are not trained in this case. He is using chi2 for selecting the features

Comment: My understanding of the question is that he has already selected the top features from SelectKBest in `'colnames_selected'` by using `X_train` (which he splitted from `train_test_split`) and now want to use them into `cross_val_score` along with `forest`. Please correct me if I am wrong

Comment: Indeed he does, but the estimator is different in both cases. There shouldn't be a case of data leakage here, right ? I was under the impression that selectKbest returns the indices of the columns using a chi square test. Then he is training those features using a totally different classifier. I am not sure how this will lead to data leakage. Please correct me if I am wrong here :)

Comment: Yes. But the features have been selected from the same data. So I think that will impact the `cross_val_score` results when those features are used. For example, it may give higher than natural scores on the test folds which resemble the `X_train` from `train_test_split` and that increase the mean and user will think the model to be nice, but may not work well.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173737/discussion-between-mohammed-kashif-and-vivek-kumar).